# error: Conflict: Constraint universe:modules@0.6.4 is not satisfied by universe:modules 0.1.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am trying to add package but getting error

```
meteor add universe:carousel
 => Errors while adding packages:
```

While selecting package versions:

```
error: Conflict: Constraint universe:modules@0.6.4 is not 
satisfied by universe:modules 0.1.0.
Constraints on package "universe:modules":
```

Not sure whats causing this *constraint/conflict*. I am pasting contents of *.meteor/versions*

```
accounts-base@1.2.14
accounts-password@1.3.3
alanning:roles@1.2.15
aldeed:collection2@2.10.0
aldeed:collection2-core@1.2.0
aldeed:schema-deny@1.1.0
aldeed:schema-index@1.1.1
aldeed:simple-schema@1.5.3
allow-deny@1.0.5
audit-argument-checks@1.0.7
autoupdate@1.3.12
babel-compiler@6.13.0
babel-runtime@1.0.1
base64@1.0.10
binary-heap@1.0.10
blaze@2.3.0
blaze-tools@1.0.10
boilerplate-generator@1.0.11
browser-policy@1.0.9
browser-policy-common@1.0.11
browser-policy-content@1.0.12
browser-policy-framing@1.0.12
caching-compiler@1.1.9
caching-html-compiler@1.1.0
callback-hook@1.0.10
check@1.2.4
coffeescript@1.11.1_4
dburles:factory@1.1.0
ddp@1.2.5
ddp-client@1.3.2
ddp-common@1.2.8
ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.6
ddp-server@1.3.12
deps@1.0.12
diff-sequence@1.0.7
ecmascript@0.6.1
ecmascript-runtime@0.3.15
ejson@1.0.13
email@1.1.18
es5-shim@4.6.15
fastclick@1.0.13
fortawesome:fontawesome@4.7.0
fourseven:scss@3.13.0
geojson-utils@1.0.10
hot-code-push@1.0.4
html-tools@1.0.11
htmljs@1.0.11
http@1.2.10
id-map@1.0.9
jquery@1.11.10
launch-screen@1.1.0
livedata@1.0.18
localstorage@1.0.12
logging@1.1.16
mdg:validated-method@1.1.0
mdg:validation-error@0.5.1
meteor@1.6.0
meteor-base@1.0.4
minifier-css@1.2.15
minifier-js@1.2.15
minimongo@1.0.19
mobile-experience@1.0.4
mobile-status-bar@1.0.13
modules@0.7.7
modules-runtime@0.7.8
mongo@1.1.14
mongo-id@1.0.6
npm-bcrypt@0.9.2
npm-mongo@2.2.16_1
observe-sequence@1.0.14
ordered-dict@1.0.9
practicalmeteor:chai@2.1.0_1
practicalmeteor:loglevel@1.2.0_2
practicalmeteor:mocha@2.4.5_6
practicalmeteor:mocha-core@1.0.1
practicalmeteor:sinon@1.14.1_2
promise@0.8.8
raix:eventemitter@0.1.3
random@1.0.10
rate-limit@1.0.6
reactive-dict@1.1.8
reactive-var@1.0.11
reload@1.1.11
retry@1.0.9
routepolicy@1.0.12
service-configuration@1.0.11
session@1.1.7
sha@1.0.9
shell-server@0.2.1
spacebars@1.0.13
spacebars-compiler@1.1.0
srp@1.0.10
standard-minifier-css@1.3.2
standard-minifier-js@1.2.1
static-html@1.2.0
templating@1.3.0
templating-compiler@1.3.0
templating-runtime@1.3.0
templating-tools@1.1.0
themeteorchef:bert@2.1.1
tmeasday:test-reporter-helpers@0.2.1
tracker@1.1.1
ui@1.0.12
underscore@1.0.10
url@1.0.11
webapp@1.3.12
webapp-hashing@1.0.9
xolvio:backdoor@0.2.1
xolvio:cleaner@0.3.1
```

Comment: i had to upgrade few npm modules (meteor npm update) fixed outdated dependency issue.

Answer (score 1):

i had to upgrade few npm modules (meteor npm update) fixed outdated dependency issue.